# Text Jumping out of the Column

Tags: html, css

i have this [script](http://leb-media.com/fouadlb/files/GermanySupporters/Scores2/phpmydatagrid-2011-09-27/sample9.php)
It's a script that allow me to edit database tables through the web.
Everything works perfect except that if a column has large word without space between as u can see if u open the link of the script i posted, it's jumping on the column next to it...
i been messing with the css and the whole codes of the script but couldn't get this thing fixed...

those are all my codes...

My css code :

```
body{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.dgError{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border:5px double #C0C0C0;
    padding:5px;
}
.dgMainDiv{
    width:98%;

}
.dgTable{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:95%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.dgTitles{
    font-size:105%;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    border:1px solid;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
    border-right-color:#aca899;
    border-top-color:#ece9d8;
    border-top-width:2px;
    border-bottom-color:#ece9d8;
}
.dgTitles:hover{
    border-top-color:#ffc83c;
}
.dgImgLink{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:2px;
}
.dgImgLink:hover{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.dgHeader{
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border:solid 1px #A0A0A0;
    height:30px;
}
.dgFooter{
    font-size:9px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    color:#000000;
}
.dgPagRow{
    background:#EFEFEF;
    border-top:solid 1px #bfcacd;
    font-size:9px;
}
.dgBold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgLinks{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#0000FF;
}
.dgLinks:hover{
    color:#FF0000;
}
.dgSelectpage{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:9px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgRownorm{
    font-size:100%;
    border:1px solid #bfcacd;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom-style:none;
}
.dgRowalt{
    font-size:100%;
    border:1px solid #bfcacd;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom-style:none;
}
.dgRowsnormTR, .dgspnormRow{
    height:20px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
}
.dgRowsnormTR:hover{
    background-color:#ffffe0;
}
.dgRowsaltTR, .dgspaltRow{
    height:20px;
    background-color:#e9eff2;
    color:#000000;
}
.dgRowsaltTR:hover{
    background-color:#ffffe0;
}
.dgspnormRow{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgspaltRow{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgAjax{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#FFFFE1; 
    border-style: dotted; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 4px;
}
.dgArrows{
    width:5px; 
    height:15px;
}
.dgInput {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #6699FF; 
    padding-left: 4px; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.dgInput:focus{
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
.dgSearchDiv {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute; 
    width:300px; 
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#0a246a; 
    border:2px solid #0a246a;
    top:0; 
    z-index: 10000; 
    display:none; 
}
.dgInnerDiv {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    font-size:100%;
    height:130px;
}
.dgSearchTit {
    width:270px; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    cursor:move;
    float:left;
}
.dgCheck{
    width: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #6699FF; 
}
.dgTotRowsTR{
    height:25px;
    background-color:#ece9d8;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgRowsTot{
    border:1px solid #bfcacd;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
}
.dgAddDiv{
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

/* --- This options below produce an error in FF 3 --- */
/*
    opacity: .98; 
    -moz-opacity:0.98; 
*/
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.dgAddTitle{
    background-color: #000099; 
    height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgAddNames{
    width: 200px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.dgAddInputs{
    width: 180px;
}
.dgAddButons{
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #CCC; 
}
```

**Main page code** = http://pastebin.com/44qgpeti

**PHP Script code** = http://pastebin.com/LqavqHdx

I posted both my `css` and `script` in case the problem is not in the `CSS` file...

So I'm hoping someone could help me find this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS word-wrap to split those words that are extremely large:

```
.dgRownorm {
    border-style: solid solid none;
    font-size: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You can check the Browser compatibility table [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap#AutoCompatibilityTable).

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the overflow to hidden:

```
.dgRownorm{
    font-size:100%;
    border:1px solid #bfcacd;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom-style:none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will cut off any extra text if the size of the cell is set. If you want the text to wrap instead, you could look at the PHP `wordwrap` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use **css word-wrap property**.

set `word-wrap: break-word;` in th div css wherever you are facing out of the box text issue.

```
.dgRownorm{
    font-size:100%;
    border:1px solid #bfcacd;
    border-left-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom-style:none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```